# Send Excel table in Outlook Mail without using Display

Tags: vba, outlook

When I use the `.Send` command instead of `.Display` the table does not paste in sent emails.

I use below code I want to `.Send` email without `.Display`.

```
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "" & " " & Range("A2") & "-  " & Range("A3")
    .Body = ""
  
    .Display
    
    Set OutlookInspector = .GetInspector
    
    Set WordDocument = OutlookInspector.WordEditor

        Sheets("Format").Range("Table1[#All]").Copy
    
    Set WordRange = WordDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        WordRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
    Set WordRange = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
        WordRange.PasteExcelTable True, False, True
    
    Set WordTable = WordDocument.Tables(WordDocument.Tables.Count)
        WordTable.AllowAutoFit = True
        WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
    
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Amended code below

```
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .To = "" ' Add recipient
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "" & " " & Range("A2") & "-  " & Range("A3")
    .Body = ""
    
    Set OutlookInspector = .GetInspector
    
    Set WordDocument = OutlookInspector.WordEditor
        WordDocument.Paragraphs.Add
        
        Sheets("Format").Range("Table1[#All]").Copy
    
    Set WordRange = WordDocument.Content
        WordRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        WordRange.Paste
    
    Set WordTable = WordDocument.Tables(WordDocument.Tables.Count)
        WordTable.AllowAutoFit = True
        WordTable.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
  
    OutlookInspector.Close 0 ' This saves the document
  
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Dear Sam thank you  your code is too much helpful .. it is possible we create function with outlook Editor "GetInspector" and word Editor to send email without Display there is to realiblity like autofit table

Comment: Hi Ali, I've revised my answer for you. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sam thank you when I use OutlookInspector.Close 0  email send without Display but table not paste in send email please support

Comment: Hi Ali, with the code that you are most recently using, if you replace `.Send` with `.Display`, does the email display correctly with the table?